# Can an exact vector field have loops as solutions?

Tags: integration, analysis, self-learning, closed-form, vector-fields

I was asking myself this question. We define for an exact vector field $\mathbf{v}(\mathbf x) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, s.t. $\mathbf{v}(\mathbf x)=\nabla u(\mathbf x)$ for a potential $u$, a solution as a function $f(t):[0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f'(t)=\mathbf{v}(f(t))$ for every $t$.

The question is: if the vector field is exact, can there be solutions with $f(0)=f(T)$, i.e. closed loops ?

**Observation:** If we have the hypothesis that the vector field is always non zero maybe the situation is easier. In fact if such a solution would exist and we call $\gamma$ the associated loop, $\int_{\gamma} \mathbf{v}=\int_{\gamma} \nabla{u}=\mathbf{0}$, so the integral of the vector field along the loop should be zero. This means that the component tangent to the loop should change sign, in particular there must be a point $p$ along the loop where the component of the vector field tangent to the loop vanishes. This should be true for every loop. For our loop the vector field is also always tangent to $\gamma$, so this means that $\mathbf{v}(p)=\mathbf{0}$. But this cannot be if the vector field is always non zero.

Is the observation correct or formalizable with enough regularity conditions? And what about exact vector fields that can vanish? Are there general results on the loops that an exact vector field can have?

Comment: Do you mean $f'(t)$ instead of $\nabla f(t)$?

Comment: yeah you are right I change the notation I hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all notice that if $\mathbf{v}$ has a zero, say in $\mathbf{x}_0$, then a solution trivially exists by choosing $f(t)\equiv\mathbf{x}_0$.

Your observation is correct. Indeed, we find for any solution $f\in C^1([0,T];\mathbb{R}^n)$ by the chain rule
$$0=\int_0^T[u(f(t))]'\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^T\nabla u(f(t))\cdot f'(t)\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^T\mathbf{v}(f(t))\cdot f'(t)\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^T\vert f'(t)\vert^2\mathrm{d}t$$
and thus $f\equiv f_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ must be constant. From this we conclude
$$\mathbf{v}(f_0)=f_0'=0.$$

Comment: Nice so you proved that the only loops for an exact field are the trivial loops with image constant where the vector field vanishes

Comment: Combining your hint at the beginning with the reasoning of my observation we could also convince intuitively that this is the case. A non trivial loop cannot contain a point where the vector field vanishes because otherwise we would be have two different solutions of a cauchy problem, the loop and the constant one

Comment: @Thomas Exactly.

Comment: Great thanks for the nice answer. So I think there are no open points on this. Accepting the answer if it is OK for you.

Comment: @Thomas , or perhaps junjios: I am a bit confused about the sentence "A non trivial loop cannot contain a point where the vector field vanishes...": The vector field $(-y,x)$ vanishes at the origin and all its solutions are circles around the origin. Edit: sorry now I get it: you mean that that point cannot lie *on* the loop.

Comment: Yes exactly I meant on the loop. But that at this stage was just a bit of an informal argument complementing the observation in the OP. Thanks anyway for making it clear so that also other readers do not get confused.